# Spring Security JWT - Postman authentication through Authorization header works but from my Angular front end doesn't work

Tags: java, angular, spring-security, jwt, postman

I have a web application with Java, Spring Boot and Spring Security on the backend, and Angular on the front end. 

I have implemented login with Spring Security and the authentication seems to work - in Postman as well as in my application's front end I receive a jwt token. Both tokens seem to be correct, because no matter if I use the token acquired in Postman or in front end, when I send any of these tokens in Authorization header when making other requests to the server, the token is accepted by my application's back end and I get 200 OK response from the server. 

But here's where things go separate ways: **my request is only authorized when I send it from Postman. When I send (I think)the same request from my app's front end, back end throws 403 forbidden**. Naturally I assumed that I must send the request differently from my front end than I send from Postman, but I just can't find any difference. From what I see I send the same method, same body, same headers (with the authorization token) 

Do you have any idea what might be going on there?

Comment: Can you show request's header from angular to spring app?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that was that I needed to enable cors in Spring Security in the class extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter :

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors().and()
```